# Django url end href error: Reverse for '' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django

as a beginner in Django, I have a problem with producing the correct link to the edit form.

If you manually type in the address

> localhost:8000/edit/1

from your browser i receive a form for editing.

views.py

```
def edit(request, stat_id):
    stat = fms.objects.get(pk=stat_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = fmsForm(request.POST, instance=stat)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/fmstat/') 
    else:
        form = fmsForm(instance=stat)

    return render(request, 'fmstat/edit.html', {'form': form,})
```

url.py

```
url(r'^edit/(?P<stat_id>(\d+))', 'fmstat.views.edit'),
```

link in template:

```
<a href="{% url fmstat.views.edit %}">link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the `stat_id`

```
{% url fmstat.views.edit stat_id=some_id %}
```

Also its a good approach to use the url name in url tag:

```
url(r'^edit/(?P<stat_id>(\d+))',
     'fmstat.views.edit', {},
      name='stat_edit'),
```

then:

```
{% url stat_edit stat_id=some_id %}
```

Comment: This is displayed as a list of forms and I do not know how to pass the string to make it suitable to each url some_id.

Comment: If the setting link {% url fmstat.views.edit stat_id=1 %} This link takes me to localhost: 8000/edit/1. I would like to id to each link was automatically added.